# Inner padding and border for a flex-box 2x2 grid

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have some issue with 2x2 that I tried to achive using flexbox. I'm trying to achieve something like this.

[image]

Every single grid should contain equal amount of padding. Also it's required to add borders only inside. (Within the grid, like a cross)

This is the code that I've come up with but it doesn't work properly.

HTML

```
<div class="info-box">
<div class="info-item grid1"></div>
<div class="info-item grid2"></div>
<div class="info-item grid3"></div>
<div class="info-item grid4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info-box {
margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-direction: column;
.info-item {
  flex: 1 1 calc(50%);
  background: $light;
  &:nth-child(odd) {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}
}
```

How can I have some text inside those individual 4 grids and have some padding around it. Also I'm trying to add the border only inside. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply achieve the cross using `border` on the inner elements and `padding` on the container. Also no need to specify flex direction as in your case it should be `row` (the default value). Don't forget to add `box-sizing: border-box` to avoid any overflow issue.

So you may try something like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info-box {
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  padding:50px;
}

.info-item {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding:50px;
}
.grid1 {
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.grid2 {
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
}
.grid3 {
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
}
.grid4 {
  border-left:1px solid;
  border-top:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box">
  <div class="info-item grid1">1</div>
  <div class="info-item grid2">2</div>
  <div class="info-item grid3">3</div>
  <div class="info-item grid4">4</div>
</div>
```

Or another solution to avoid the use of border is using pseudo element like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info-box {
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  padding:50px;
  position:relative;
}
.info-box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:#000;
  width:2px;
  right:50%;
  margin-right:-1px;
  top:50px;
  bottom:50px;
}
.info-box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:#000;
  height:2px;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-1px;
  left:50px;
  right:50px;
}

.info-item {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box">
  <div class="info-item grid1">1</div>
  <div class="info-item grid2">2</div>
  <div class="info-item grid3">3</div>
  <div class="info-item grid4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works :) But what if we take padding element from individual boxes and center in vertically. How can I do that?

Comment: @AnjanaNilupul remove the paddin from the elemen and add these styles `display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;` then you content will be centered vertically and also horizontally ;)