# 4 quadrant div with logo div in center

Tags: html, css

I am looking to have 4 divs (2x2) with a logo div in the middle.

I came across this so far: [Example found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669802/inner-padding-and-border-for-a-flex-box-2x2-grid)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info-box {
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  padding:50px;
}

.info-item {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding:50px;
}
.grid1 {
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.grid2 {
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
}
.grid3 {
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
}
.grid4 {
  border-left:1px solid;
  border-top:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box">
  <div class="info-item grid1">1</div>
  <div class="info-item grid2">2</div>
  <div class="info-item grid3">3</div>
  <div class="info-item grid4">4</div>
</div>
```

This works perfect. All I would like to do is add a div right in the middle that would hold either a logo or text etc.

I have drawn up a basic example of what I would like it to look like.

[image]

Comment: use position absolute with the logo and make it in the center

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply place a `div` over everything else with `position` for example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.info-box {
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  padding:50px;
}
.info-item {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding:50px;
}
.grid1 {
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.grid2 {
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
}
.grid3 {
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
}
.grid4 {
  border-left:1px solid;
  border-top:1px solid;
}
.logo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box">
  <div class="info-item grid1">1</div>
  <div class="info-item grid2">2</div>
  <div class="info-item grid3">3</div>
  <div class="info-item grid4">4</div>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
</div>
```